# Best practice for pass info from Service to Activity (or Fragment)

Tags: android, android-fragments, socket.io, android-service

I am running a `Socket.IO` client on my `Android` app and I am having trouble passing data from the `Service` (that handles the connection of the socket) to one of the `Fragments`.

In one of my `Activities`, I open up a fragment that has a profile page. When the profile fragment opens, I emit an event to the server asking for the profile information.

I am getting the information back from the server with no problems, but I am having trouble sending that data (a JSON string) to the current fragment.

What would be the best practice to pass this information from the `Service` to the `Fragment` (or the `Activity`)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `bind` to the `service` from `Activity` and create a `service connection`. So that you will have the `instance` of `service` to communicate.

See my answer here [How to pass a handler from activity to service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22573301/how-to-pass-a-handler-from-activity-to-service/22573715#22573715) *on how to bind to service and establish a service connection.*

Apart from this, have an `interface` defined in your service

```
public interface OnServiceListener{
    public void onDataReceived(String data);
}
```

Add a `set Listener` method in `service` to register the listener from `Activity`

```
private OnServiceListener mOnServiceListener = null;

public void setOnServiceListener(OnServiceListener serviceListener){
    mOnServiceListener = serviceListener;
}
```

Next, In your Activity implement the Listener interface

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity 
        implements CustomService.OnServiceListener{

```
    @Override
    public void onDataReceived(String data) {

     }
}
```

Next, When the service connection is established , register the listener

```
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
        customService = ((CustomService.LocalBinder) iBinder).getInstance();
        customService.setOnServiceListener(MainActivity.this);
    }
```

Now, When you receive the data in service pass the data to the Activity through `onDataReceived` method.

```
if(mOnServiceListener != null){
        mOnServiceListener.onDataReceived("your data");
    }
```